# Spring: JDBC Template Invalid column type

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Using the following code to get the list of data from table but getting invalid column error.

```
String sql = "select * from employees  WHERE emp_status = :statusCode";
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("statusCode", "Active");
MapSqlParameterSource parametersSourceMap = new MapSqlParameterSource(parameters );

List<Employee> employees rowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, parametersSourceMap);
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select * from employees  WHERE emp_status = :statusCode SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
        at com.spring.EmployeeDAOImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:46)
        at com.spring.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:33)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```

Table have column as Varchar2

Anyone have idea why we can't get data based on String column?

Comment: Something tells me that's not the method that raises the exception. Can you please show the code for method `EmployeeDAOImpl#addEmployee`?

Comment: The error is occur here `EmployeeDAOImpl.java:46` and you are showing code that not related to this error

Comment: line 46 is List<Employee> employees rowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, parametersSourceMap)

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza am not adding through JDBCTemplate. selectEmployee. Will chnage the methodName

Comment: You are using `JdbcTemplate` whereas you probably want to use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced the same issue. In my case, I was using JdbcTemplate instead of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. I am not sure if the issue is same for you.

You can define a bean of type NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and then autowire it in your repository class.

Configuration class :

```
@Bean
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate yourNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(DataSource yourDataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(yourDataSource);
}
```

Repository class :

```
@Repository
public class YourRepositoryImpl implements YourRepository {

@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass parameters like this :

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_status = ?";
List<Employee> employees = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
        sql,
        new Object[]{"Active"},
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Employee>(Employee.class)
);
```